# Unable to link a column in datatables

Tags: java, datatables

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Populating JSP</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />

</head>
<body>
    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>

     <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#example').dataTable( {
                    serverSide: true,
                    "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
                        $('td:eq(2)', nRow).html('<a href="http://www.google.com' + aData[2] + '">' +
                            aData[2] + '</a>');
                        return nRow;
                    },
                    ajax : {
                        url: 'hello/data1',
                        dataType:'json',
                        type: 'POST'

                    }

                }

                 );
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have 2 coulmns, ID and Salary. I am linking the salary to google.com, for that I am using fnRowCallback function. But that doesn't seem to work. Where do you think I am going wrong. The jsp is shown above.

Comment: first thing, see that your server endpoint is giving you the correct result (use any client, chrome's POSTmaster may be), Then see if your data table is rendering the data correclty if there is any issue with rendering data, then go through DATATABLES forum. here http://www.datatables.net/forums/

Comment: Yes, I think I am getting the correct result. What is the issue with rendering data?

Answer (score 0):

Use custom column definition [columnDefs](http://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html) to alter column rendering.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
                serverSide: true,
                "aoColumnDefs" : [
                 {
                      "mData": "name",                         
                      "sClass": "dataTable-user-list-name",
                     "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                          return '<a href="/#/' + oObj.aData['detailsUrl'] + '">oObj.aData['name']<a>'
                 }],                   
                ajax : {
                    url: 'hello/data1',
                    dataType:'json',
                    type: 'POST'

                }

            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am new to datatables. I have 2 columns (id and salary). 

What is 
mData and corresponding name with it?
sClass and dataTable-user-list-name?
aData and detailsUrl inside it?

Simple little help would do.